# Entity Framework subselect

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to bring back results based on a username matching a company. there are 5 tables involved. can i do a subselect (obviously not) or what is the best way to do this.

```
db.Displays
     .Include(d => d.Location)
     .Include(d => d.Location.Region)
     .Include(d => d.Location.Region.Company.Users.Where(p=> p.LoginName == userName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to apply the first two `Includes`, with the third you should be able to include the levels that you need:

```
var displays= db.Displays.Include(d=>d.Location.Region.Company.Users).Where(d=>d.Location.Region.Company.Users.Any(p=>p.LoginName== userName));
```

After the `Include`, you need to call the `Where` method to filter the Displays by the condition(s) that you want to apply.

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) to see how works the [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method.

Comment: You're welcome ;). If you think my answer helped you to solve your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.